# Cassandra Update or Insert when KEY already exists as Batch

Tags: merge, cassandra, batch-processing, cql

I imagine with Cassandra 2.0 + using CQL this will look something like

```
BATCH BEGIN;
UPDATE keyspace.Table SET column = "value" IF EXISTS
INSERT keyspace.Table (...) VALUES (...) IF NOT EXISTS
BATCH END;
```

basically two statements for each item to be inserted/updated; This basically should mimic the MERGE behaviour of T-SQL

Is this a right assumption for the task I'd like to perform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`INSERT` and `UPDATE` in CQL are the same call under the covers, because on the storage layer, you only really have updates anyway. In CQL, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are exposed as syntactic sugar to make CQL feel more like SQL. There are slight nuances, such as the `UPDATE` statement taking a `WHERE` clause and also being used to increment counter tables, but they don't really affect the underlying PUT semantics when CQL is translated to the storage layer.

`IF NOT EXISTS` used with an `INSERT` or `IF` used with an `UPDATE` in CQL tells Cassandra to execute a compare and swap operation on the backend. This means that the operation will only get executed if the pre-condition is met. This requires consensus, so in a distributed setting (e.g. more than 1 Cassandra node), this might incur a performance penalty.

So given this, I don't think that this mirrors the SQL MERGE behavior. The thing that it does have in common is that both variants require the server to acquire a row lock in order to perform the operation atomically.

Comment: yeah.. did a bit more reading and this made all to much sense; thanks for the detailed answer though.